# Unable to allow users access to SVN repo, what could be the cause?

Tags: centos6, svn, conf

I've installed a SVN server and configured a repository inside it. It is accessible by Apache.
I've allowed access to 3 users, here are the repository conf files:

```
[root@afdev conf]# egrep -v '^#' *
authz:
authz:[aliases]
authz:
authz:[groups]
authz:
authz:
authz:allaccess = vladimirc,antonc,oleksiyd,itaig
authz:
authz:[/]
authz:@allaccess = rw
passwd:
passwd:[users]
passwd:antonc = XXX
passwd:oleksiyd = XXX
passwd:vladimirc = XXX
passwd:itaig = XXX
svnserve.conf:
svnserve.conf:
svnserve.conf:[general]
svnserve.conf:anon-access = none
svnserve.conf:auth-access = write
svnserve.conf:password-db = passwd
svnserve.conf:authz-db = authz
svnserve.conf:realm = kiev_repo
svnserve.conf:
svnserve.conf:[sasl]
[root@afdev conf]#
```

But for some reason which I can't find, when I browse to `http://svn_server/svn/repo` I get asked to enter a password and when I enter credentials of one of the specified above users, the password window pops up again like the credentials are not accepted.
After editing the files in the `repo conf` directory I did `service svnserve restart ; service httpd restart` but it seems like the users are still unable to log into the SVN repository.
What could be wrong? What have I missed?

Comment: Have you tried using an svn client, or are you just using a web browser?

Comment: I've tried a web browser and locally from the server using one of the specified users credentials.

Comment: After editing these files, shall I run `service svnserve restart` or any other command to reflect the changes I did in the configuration files?

Comment: So is it svnserve or Apache HTTP Server? If you use Apache, then you don't need to configure svnserve at all.

Comment: Okay, good to know, I've also tried adding user using `htpasswd -c /path/to/.htpasswd-users user1` but this user is not able to log into the SVN server as well, am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the problem and fixed it.
It seems like the file which holds the users and encrypted password is `/etc/svn-auth-users` rather than the passwd file in the `repo/conf` directory.
I used `htpasswd -m /etc/svn-auth-users user1` , set a password and then I was able to log into the SVN server using `http://svn_server/repo` with the newly created credentials.
I still don't understand why the `/home/svn/repo/conf/passwd` file is being ignored and `/etc/svn-auth-users` is used but since everything works now and my users are able to log into the SVN server - I have no complains.

Comment: In regards to it ignoring the conf/passwd file, check the SASL setting in your svnserve.conf. If it's enabled, it overrides the passwd-db setting.